# Why my TableLayout doesnt match different type of android screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout inside my activity it works well in Pixel API 29 which is an android Pie like this one https://ibb.co/T138m8G.

but when I tried my app in lower android version like android 6.0 my TableLayout would be like this. https://ibb.co/ZK6VPcT

This is my java code

FormReports.java

```
public class FormReports extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn, btnshare;
private LinearLayout llScroll;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_reports);
btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
llScroll = findViewById(R.id.llScroll);
btnshare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
Toast.makeText(this, "Reports", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
FormReports context = this;

DatabaseHelper dataHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);

TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(context);
rowHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0"));
rowHeader.setLayoutParams(new 
TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
String[] headerText = {"DATE", "COMPANY NAME", "DETAILS", "TIME IN", 
"TIME OUT", "REMARKS"};
for (String c : headerText) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new 
 TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextSize(8);
    tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    tv.setText(c);
    tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
    rowHeader.addView(tv);
}
tableLayout.addView(rowHeader);

// Get data from sqlite database and add them to the table
// Open the database for reading
SQLiteDatabase db = dataHelper.getReadableDatabase();
// Start the transaction.
db.beginTransaction();

try {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + 
 DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME_OUT;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Read columns data

            String out_td = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_date"));
            String out_co = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_cu"));
            String out_st = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_st"));
            String out_in = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_in"));
            String out_out = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_out"));
            String out_le = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timei_legend"));

            // data rows
            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            row.setLayoutParams(new 
 TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
 TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            String[] colText = {out_td,
                                out_co,
                                out_st,
                                out_in,
                                out_out,
                                out_le};

            for (String text : colText) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new 
 TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
 TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(7);
                tv.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                tv.setText(text);
                tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
 R.color.black));
                row.addView(tv);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }

    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (Exception e) {

}




btnshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ShareFile();
        } else {
            ShareFile();
        }
    }
});

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("size"," "+llScroll.getWidth() +"  
"+llScroll.getWidth());
        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(llScroll, llScroll.getWidth(), 
llScroll.getHeight());
        createPdf();
    }
});
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, 
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void createPdf(){
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
//  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels ;
float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels ;
int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

//        Resources mResources = getResources();
//        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, 
R.drawable.screenshot);

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new 
PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawPaint(paint);

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, 
convertHighet, true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
document.finishPage(page);

// write the document content
String targetPdf = "/sdcard/timerecords.pdf";
File filePath;
filePath = new File(targetPdf);
try {
    document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// close the document
document.close();
Toast.makeText(this, "PTAF CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void ShareGif() {
} 

protected void ShareFile() {
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
"/");
String fileName = "timerecords.pdf";
File sharingGifFile = new File(exportDir, fileName);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
// Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FormReports.this, 
"com.example.serviceapplication.provider", sharingGifFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Time 
 Records"));
}
}
```

and this is my XML code

activity_form_reports.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="false"
tools:context=".FormTimeIn"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TableLayout
android:id= "@+id/tablelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:shrinkColumns="0"
app:tabTextColor="@color/black">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="PAYROLL AND TIMEKEEPING AUTHORIZATION FORM"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView android:text="Department:"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView android:text="Cutt off Period:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tablerow1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="314dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Service Department"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prepared By:"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Checked By:"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Approved By:"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Received By:"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

 </GridLayout>

 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:textColor="@color/black">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Employees Signature"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Immediate Supervisor's Signature"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Department Manager's Signature"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:textSize="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HRD Manager/Staff's Signature"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:textSize="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

 </GridLayout>

<View
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:background="@color/black"
/>

<GridLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="GENERATE PTAF"
android:layout_columnWeight="0"
android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_share"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="SEND PTAF"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:width="150dp"
android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</GridLayout>
```

I just want to make the output same as the first image I show you in any size of Mobile phones thank you so much.

I also tried to set layout_widths to match_parent like this and removed shrinkColumns="0"

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llScroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TableLayout
android:id= "@+id/tablelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:shrinkColumns="0"
app:tabTextColor="@color/black">
```

but the effect is like this https://ibb.co/zR7zpjT

Anyone please help me identified my problem I really need this to work :( thank you so much.